# What would the random effect structure be for this experimental design?

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme

In my experiment, There are two fixed effects, Temperature and Condition with 4 and 3 levels respectively. There are total of 12 different containers, 3 per temperature and individuals of all 3 Conditions were reared together in each container. Since a container was shared by all condition treatments but only experiences one temperature, I am modelling it using a linear mixed effects model as -

`Response variable ~ Temperature * Condition + (1|Temperature:Container)`

I want to follow this up with an anova. Is using the current random effects structure the correct approach?

Comment: Are your observational units the containers or the individuals?

Comment: Observational units are Individuals. We measure things like body weight after they are fully grown.

Comment: @Sointu It depends on how the containers were labeled. It might be that only the interaction of temperature treatment and container label results in a unique ID.

Comment: @Roland yes I started thinking about this further and came to the same conclusion. I'll delete my earlier comment.